# how to replace same values in multiple columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataframe looks like this:

```
    PD_DK    WARNSPEAK_DK
1    88         88
2    Nan         1    
3    88          1
4    1           1
```

here is my code(it's basically replacing 88 vavlue to 999999):

```
df2.replace({['PD_DK','WARNSPEAK_DK','TIME1','TIME2','TIME3','TIME4','WARNBEHAV_DK','TIME5','TIME6','TIME7',
            'TIME8','WARNEMOTION_DK','TIME9','TIME10','TIME11','TIME12']: 88}, 999999, inplace=True)
# to check
df2['PD_DK'].value_counts()
```

and I got the output such as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [31], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df2.replace({['PD_DK','WARNSPEAK_DK','TIME1','TIME2','TIME3','TIME4','WARNBEHAV_DK','TIME5','TIME6','TIME7',
      2             'TIME8','WARNEMOTION_DK','TIME9','TIME10','TIME11','TIME12']: 88}, 999999, inplace=True)
      3 df2['PD_DK'].value_counts()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Try to write it in a more clear way, it's difficult to get what you want your code to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use if need specify columns by list:

```
cols = ['PD_DK','WARNSPEAK_DK','TIME1','TIME2','TIME3','TIME4','WARNBEHAV_DK','TIME5','TIME6',
        'TIME7','TIME8','WARNEMOTION_DK','TIME9','TIME10','TIME11','TIME12']
df2[cols] = df2[cols].replace({88: 999999})
```

Or create nested dictionaries in dict comprehension:

```
df2 = df2.replace({x:{88: 999999} for x in cols})
```